# Late Binding Issue with BackgroundWorker in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker, late-binding

I am running a BackgroundWorker, and want to report its progress. In the example below I create a test list which the BackgroundWorker then iterates through. The problem lies in the line 'sender.ReportProgress(i)'. If I have Option Strict on, it does not like my use of 'i' due to Late Binding issues. Is there any alternative way to code this and avoid that issue?

```
    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Configuring for Background Workers
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

        Dim MyList As New List(Of String)
        For a As Integer = 0 To 100
            MyList.Add(CStr(a))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim bgw As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
        bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        AddHandler bgw.DoWork, AddressOf bgw_DoWork
        ' I create a BackgroundWorker here rather than add one in the toolbox so that I can specify the Handler and use different Handler routines for different part of a large program.

        Button1.Enabled = False
        Dim progress As New Progress(bgw)
        progress.ShowDialog()
        Button1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
        For i = 0 To MyList.Count -1
            Label1.Text = MyList(i)
            sender.ReportProgress(i)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
            Label1.Refresh()
        Next

    End Sub

End Class


Public Class Progress
    Private WithEvents _BGW As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

    Public Sub New(ByVal BGW As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)
        _BGW = BGW
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmProgress_Shown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        If Not IsNothing(_BGW) Then
            _BGW.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub _BGW_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles _BGW.ProgressChanged
        ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
        Label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage
    End Sub

    Private Sub _BGW_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles _BGW.RunWorkerCompleted
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It is not the `i` it has a problem with, it is the `ReportProgress` method - `System.Object` has no such method. There are several other issues. On a side note, you should visit the [tour] page - your past 3 posts have 5 answers but all remain open because none of the answers have been accepted,

Comment: Thanks for your comments. What are the other issues? OK about the Acceptance - I hadn't realised that I was supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CType(sender, BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i)
```

Comment: Just a little note: It is better (and faster) to use [**`DirectCast`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/directcast-operator) when the object type is known. `CType` is supposed to be used when converting to a _**different**_ type (for instance converting a `Byte` to an `Integer`, although this is usually done implicitly when not using `Option Strict`).

Comment: The difference between the two is that `CType` tries to use [**conversion operators**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-define-a-conversion-operator) to perform a conversion, and if that fails it'll try casting instead. `DirectCast` only does casting and is therefore much faster than `CType` when you are not looking to convert an object to a different type.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want to do multiple actions with it, then create a local reference variable like this:

```
Private Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)

    Dim bgw As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = DirectCast(sender, System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)

    ' ... now you can use "bgw" multiple times below instead of casting each time ...

    For i = 0 To MyList.Count -1
        Label1.Text = MyList(i)
        bgw.ReportProgress(i)
        bgw.SomethingElse()
        bgw.MoreStuff()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
        Label1.Refresh()
    Next
End Sub
```

Obviously this isn't necessary in your case, just an FYI...